# Please advise on the exception

Tags: java, database, oracle, ssl

Can any body tell me what this exception means, its confusing because I tried all possible ways to change the path of the keystore.. doesn't work.

Environment: ORACLE database server, configuring SSL

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: 

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:414)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
 at project1.JDBCSSLTest.getConnection(JDBCSSLTest.java:42)
 at project1.JDBCSSLTest.run(JDBCSSLTest.java:22)
 at project1.JDBCSSLTest.main(JDBCSSLTest.java:49)
```

The java class I am using is.

```
package project1;

import java.security.Security;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver;

public class JDBCSSLTest
{

public JDBCSSLTest()
{
 // must enable this
 Security.addProvider(new oracle.security.pki.OraclePKIProvider());
}

public void run () throws SQLException
{
 Connection conn = getConnection();
 System.out.println("Auto Commit = " + conn.getAutoCommit());
 conn.close();
}

public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException
{
 String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)" +
              "(HOST=localhost)(PORT=2484))" +
              "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))";
 java.util.Properties props = new java.util.Properties();

 props.setProperty("user", "system");
 props.setProperty("password", "weblogic");
    props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C://lib//ewallet.p12");
    props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType","PKCS12");
    props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","weblogic123");
  props.setProperty("oracle.net.ssl_cipher_suites", "SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA");

 DriverManager.registerDriver(new OracleDriver());
 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
 return conn;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException
{
 JDBCSSLTest dSTest = new JDBCSSLTest();
 dSTest.run();
 System.out.println("all done..");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this Oracle document](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/wp-oracle-jdbc-thin-ssl-130128.pdf):

> ```
> “java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>  Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: 
>  the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty”:
> ```
>
> if you are using PKCS12
>   wallets and Oracle’s PKI provider isn’t properly enabled. This exception
>   comes from the PKCS12 implementation from Sun (Sun’s PKI provider)
>   which isn’t compatible with Oracle wallets. Oracle’s PKI provider must be
>   properly enabled for PKCS12 either statically or dynamically if you use
>   PKCS12 wallets.

Enabling the PKI provider is described in section 2.2.4 of the same document.

Comment: Thank you so much Stephen.. i was pulling my hair from last 1 week. you just made my weekend.. its working now!!! Thanks again

Comment: I was able to get it working in JDeveloper but when I package it inside a war file it doesnt work. Please adviase

Comment: Make sure all the libraries that are included in your JDeveloper project are included in the war file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar this with this but going by the exception information along your user code was triggered

```
   at project1.JDBCSSLTest.getConnection(JDBCSSLTest.java:42)
```

and the runtime is missing a required property when retrieving a connection

```
Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

It looks as if you haven't configured this required 'trustAnchors' property.

Comment: I was able to get it working in JDeveloper but when I package it inside a war file it doesnt work. Please adviase